OpenTelemetry trace not propagating from Spring Boot 3.2.1 (opentelemetry-javaagent 2.10) to Airflow 2.10.2 REST API
I am using Spring Boot 3.2.1 with the opentelemetry-javaagent 2.10 for zero-code instrumentation. I also have Apache Airflow 2.10.2 set up with OpenTelemetry configured.
When my Spring Boot application makes a REST API call to Airflow's /dag_runs endpoint to trigger a DAG run, the trace does not propagate correctly. It appears that Airflow does not recognize or receive the traceparent and tracestate headers sent by the Spring Boot application.
Here’s what I’ve observed so far:
OpenTelemetry is successfully set up in both Spring Boot and Airflow environments.
Traces generated within Spring Boot are successfully captured.
Environment details:

Spring Boot: 3.2.1
OpenTelemetry Java Agent: 2.10
Apache Airflow: 2.10.2 (with OpenTelemetry configured)
otel collector : Grafana Alloy
Trace : Grafana Tempo
REST API endpoint being called: /api/v1/dags/<dag_id>/dagRuns

Airflow captures its own traces but does not seem to link them to the parent trace from Spring Boot.
I have confirmed that Spring Boot sends the traceparent header in the API request.
springboot Dagrun api call
Airflow DAG Trace, Set New TraceID
DAG Linked Span to Scheduler_job_loop
Is there a way to link the trace of an Airflow DAG under the captured POST trace from the Spring Boot app when calling the DAG run API?
My questions:
Is Airflow 2.10.2 supposed to automatically handle and propagate OpenTelemetry traceparent headers for REST API calls, or does it require additional configuration? 
Could the issue be related to how Airflow’s OpenTelemetry implementation processes incoming requests? 
Are there specific compatibility issues between the OpenTelemetry Java Agent (2.10) and Airflow’s OpenTelemetry support?
